# SHA256 of data stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I am having a use case where i am downloading the file from URL using GET request. Is it possible to calculate SHA256 of file stream without saving to disk or holding an entire object in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a [`MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) and [`Sink.fold`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$@fold[U,T](zero:U)(f:(U,T)=%3EU):akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[T,scala.concurrent.Future[U]]).

First we need a function to create an empty digest and a function to update a digest with a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

def emptySHA256Digest : MessageDigest = MessageDigest getInstance "SHA-256" 

val updateDigest : (MessageDigest, ByteBuffer) => MessageDigest = 
  (messageDigest, byteBuffer) => {
    messageDigest update byteBuffer
    messageDigest
  }
```

These two functions can then be used within a fold which is applied to the `entity` of an `HttpResponse` to update the digest with all `ByteString` values in the entity:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse

val responseBodyToDigest : HttpResponse => Future[MessageDigest] = 
  (_ : HttpResponse)
    .entity
    .dataBytes
    .map(_.asByteBuffer)
    .runFold(emptySHA256Digest)(updateDigest)
```

Comment: given answer is producing the wrong sha256 value. Is it calculating before stream completes? test code : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/079813d9951da3016828b83f8fd09695

Answer (score 2):

Use one of `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").update` methods.

Pass your file piece-by-piece to it.

Then call `digest()`

Sample code:

```
    MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    for(byte[] arr: source){
        instance.update(arr);
    }
    byte[] result = instance.digest();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need `Flow` which will transform one data to another data. In your case, you want to transform plain text to sha256 text.

```scala
def digest(algorithm: String = "SHA-256"): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[ByteString].fold(MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm)) {
        case (digest: MessageDigest, bytes:ByteString) => {digest.update(bytes.asByteBuffer); digest}}
          .map {case md: MessageDigest => ByteString(md.digest())}
}
```